# Is there an Objective-C equivalent to Python urllib and urllib2?

Tags: python, objective-c

Are there any equivalents in objective-c to the following python urllib2 functions?

Request, urlopen, HTTPError, HTTPCookieProRequest, urlopen, HTTPError, HTTPCookieProcessor

Also, how would I able to to this and change the method from "get" to "post"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSMutableHTTPURLRequest`, a category of `NSMutableURLRequest`, is how you set up an HTTP request.  Using that class you will specify a method (GET or POST), headers and a url.

`NSURLConnection` is how you open the connection.  You will pass in a request and delegate, and the delegate will receive data, errors and messages related to the connection as they become available.

`NSHTTPCookieStorage` is how you manage existing cookies.  There are a number of related classes in the `NSHTTPCookie` family.

With `urlopen`, you open a connection and read from it.  There is no direct equivalent to that unless you use something lower level like `CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest`.  In Objective-C everything is passive, where you are notified when events occur on the stream.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information! This will definitely make the app easier to create now.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for some combination of `NSURL`, `NSURLRequest`, `NSURLConnection`, `NSHTTPConnection`, etc.  Check out the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) for all the information you need.